# image on option value on one fiddle works but my new copy doesn't

Tags: html, jquery, jsfiddle

This will be the dumbest question I've asked, but I found this fiddle which I edited some to make it as minimal as possible:http://jsfiddle.net/5pzcoy7k/

And since It didn't work on my own site I tried to make a new fiddle with the same resouces: https://jsfiddle.net/rqLu72o1/

Why is the result different, what am I missing?

The log I get is that `$("select").msDropDown();` is not defined, but why is it defined on the other one?:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fiddle-URL is HTTPS, one is only HTTP. The one with SSL does not work since the linked resources are not behind SSL and you get an CORS-Issue.